# CakePHP "Trying to get property of non-object" error

Tags: php, cakephp

When I post the form it shows error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object [APP\Controller\UsersController.php, line 647].
```

Here the ctp file form code:

admin_highlightedstylist.ctp is

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Userhighlighted'); ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th>STYLIST LIST</th>
                        <th><?php echo $this->Form->input('stylist_id', array('empty' => 'Select Stylist')); ?></th>
                        <th>
                            <div class="submit">
                                <?php echo $this->Form->end('ADD HIGHLIGHTED'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
```

Here the controller code script, UserController.php

```
    public function admin_highlightedstylist(){
            $this->layout = 'admin';
            $this->isAdmin();
            if($this->request->is('post')){
                print_r($this->requert->data['Userhighlighted']['stylist_id']);
                exit;

            }

            $stylists = $this->User->find('list', array('conditions'=>array('is_stylist' => true,)));
            $this->set(compact('id', 'stylists'));


        }
```

How can I remove this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: what is the code on line 647?

Comment: If it is URGENT then why has it taken 26+ minutes to answer the question on the previous comment. Answer it or we are all going to ignore this question.

Comment: You could have just found that typo yourself. And would have saved a lot of minutes yourself this way.. It cannot be that urgent after all. Learn to debug code.

Comment: Voting to close as "simple typographical error" - if there are other close voters hereabouts, please consider casting the same.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to actually read the error message and do you know what it means?

`$this->requert` vs `$this->request`

It is a simple typo. The error message is IMHO very clear, it tells you that you try to use an object that doesn't exist. Pretty easy to debug if you know that.